# Elasticsearch preform "OR" search on groups of filtering criteria

Tags: elasticsearch

Overview: I have a situation where within a single index I want to preform a search to return results based on 2 different sets of criteria. Imagine a scenario where where I have an index with a data structure like what is outlined below

I want to preform some sort of query that looks at different "blocks" of criteria. Meaning I want to search by both of the following categories in a single query (if possible):

**Category One:**

- Distance / location
- Public = true

**--OR--**

**Category Two:**

- Distance / location
- Public = false
- category = "specific category"

(although this is not my exact scenario it is an illustration of what I am facing):

```
{
  "mappings" : {
    "properties" : {
      "category" : {
        "type" : "text",
        "fields" : {
          "keyword" : {
            "type" : "keyword",
            "ignore_above" : 256
          }
        }
      },
      "completed" : {
        "type" : "boolean"
      },
      "deleted" : {
        "type" : "boolean"
      },
      "location" : {
        "type" : "geo_point"
      },
      "public" : {
        "type" : "boolean"
      },
      "uuid" : {
        "type" : "text",
        "fields" : {
          "keyword" : {
            "type" : "keyword",
            "ignore_above" : 256
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Please note: I am rather new to Elastic and would appreciate any help with this. I have attempted to search for this question but was not able to find what I was looking for. Please let me know if there is any missing information here I should include.

Comment: please remember to mark the answer as correct if it was useful for your problem or let me know if you need anything else

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can combine bool queries

```
POST test_user2737876/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "filter": [
              {
                "geo_distance": {
                  "distance": "200km",
                  "location": {
                    "lat": 41.12,
                    "lon": -71.34
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "public": false
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "filter": [
              {
                "geo_distance": {
                  "distance": "200km",
                  "location": {
                    "lat": 41.12,
                    "lon": -71.34
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "category.keyword": "specific category"
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "public": false
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1
    }
  }
}
```